# What's the counterpart of QX11EmbedWidget in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5, x11, gtk3, qx11embedcontainer

In Qt4, we could use the `embedInto` method of the `QX11EmbedWidget` class to embed any `QWidget` into another application. But in Qt5, the `QX11EmbedWidget` class was dropped. I've been searching Google for many hours, but all I found indicated to use the `QWidget::createWindowContainer` method instead. However, as far as I understand, this method is rather a replacement for `QX11EmbedContainer`.

So here's the question: **How do we embed a Qt5-Widget into a non-Qt window?** - 
And in case it metters: The non-Qt window is Gtk3.

---

I've been asked for the **use-case**, so let me illustrate briefly: *Consider a Gtk-based application, which you are willing to extend - and the UI component, which you need, already exists, but is written in Qt. The goal is to avoid porting the application to Qt or the component to Gtk.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial approach was to request the embedding from Qt side. I had no luck with this, as I couldn't find any equivalent for `QX11EmbedWidget::embedInto` in Qt5. After giving up on this, I decided to give `XReparentWindow` a try, which was [reportedly used with success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089323/embedding-qwidget-into-x11-window). However, due to lack of documentation, I wasn't able to reproduce this. My third attempt was to initiate the embedding from *server* side, which is the Gtk window in my case. I'm glad to report, that it worked :-)

---

### For the Record: How to embed an arbitrary Qt5 Widget into a Gtk window

#### TL;DR:

1. Make sure that you write your Gtk code in a unit which is separate from the Qt part. This is necessary in order to avoid name conflicts between Qt5 and Gtk3.
2. Simply use `gtk_socket_add_id` to embed any X11 window into a `GtkSocket`.

Also see [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSocket.html) for reference, but note that the example given their doesn't even compile, because they forgot the `GTK_SOCKET` macro. On the contrary, the following code *works*.

[image: proof]

#### Details

The `QGtkWindow` class provides an interface to the Gtk window.

```
class QGtkWindow : public QObject
{

public:

    QGtkWindow();
    virtual ~QGtkWindow();

    void setCentralWidget( QWidget* const widget );
    void show();

private:

    GtkWindowAdapter gtkWindow;
    QWidget* const container;

}; // QGtkWindow
```

The `GtkWindowAdapter` class wraps the Gtk calls and isolates them from the Qt part of the application. An object of this class represents the Gtk window.

```
class GtkWindowAdapter
{

public:

    GtkWindowAdapter();
    ~GtkWindowAdapter();

    void show();
    void embed( unsigned long clientWinId );

private:

    struct Details;
    const std::auto_ptr< Details > pimpl;

}; // GtkWindowAdapter
```

When instantiated, an `GtkWindowAdapter` object first initializes Gtk,

```
static bool gtkInitialized = false;

struct GtkWindowAdapter::Details
{
    GtkWidget* widget;
    GtkWidget* socket;

    void setupUi();
};

GtkWindowAdapter::GtkWindowAdapter()
    : pimpl( new Details() )
{
    if( !gtkInitialized )
    {
        int argc = 0;
        gtk_init( &argc, NULL );
        gtkInitialized = true;
    }
    pimpl->setupUi();
}
```

and then setups the Gtk window:

```
void GtkWindowAdapter::Details::setupUi()
{
    widget = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    socket = gtk_socket_new();
    gtk_widget_show( socket );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER ( widget ), socket );
    gtk_widget_realize( socket );
}
```

You might already have noted the `embed` method which this class provides. This method initiates the embedding of any X11 window. The `show` method turns the encapsulated Gtk window visible.

```
void GtkWindowAdapter::embed( unsigned long clientWinId )
{
    gtk_socket_add_id( GTK_SOCKET( pimpl->socket ), clientWinId );
}

void GtkWindowAdapter::show()
{
    gtk_widget_show( pimpl->widget );
}
```

Now, the implementation of the `QGtkWindow` class is fairly simple. When created, it initializes a Gtk window by using the `GtkWindowApdater` and puts an empty `QWidget` into that window:

```
QGtkWindow::QGtkWindow()
    : container( new QWidget() )
{
    container->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );
    gtkWindow.embed( container->winId() );
    container->show();
}
```

When the user of the `QGtkWindow` class decides to put some widget into the window, the `setCentralWidget` is the way to go. It simply clears the parent widget, which was embedded into the Gtk window originally, then inserts the user's widget instead:

```
void QGtkWindow::setCentralWidget( QWidget* const widget )
{
    qDeleteAll( pimpl->container->layout()->children() );
    pimpl->container->layout()->addWidget( widget );
}

void QGtkWindow::show()
{
    pimpl->gtkWindow.show();
}
```

Hope this might spare somebody many hours.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from this link:

> https://forum.qt.io/topic/32785/qwindow-qwidget-qt5-x11embedding-how/2
>
> All the x11 stuff has moved to the "extras" department found on
>   Gitorious. (QX11EmbedWidgets and QX11EmbedContainer and the likes are
>   not in 5.x)

Try this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtx11extras/qx11info.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already came across  the `QX11Info` class and I really don't see how it relates to `QX11EmbedWidget`. In fact, I believe that this forum posting is misleading.

Comment: "How it relates" is: 1) "All the x11 stuff has moved to the "extras" department", and 2) the only thing in "x11extras" ... is QX11Info!

Comment: Right, *the only thing in "x11extras" is `QX11Info`*, so what does this tell us? Obviously, **not** all x11-related stuff was moved to the "extras" package. Thus, the forum posting is **wrong**.

Comment: No, the forum posting is saying "you're SOL..." ;)  These APIs don't appear to be supported any longer for QT 5.x and up.  SUGGESTION: maybe you can achieve similar functionality with something like QWidget::createWindowContainer() instead?

Comment: Maybe. This is actually what I've been reading for the past 6 hours, but noone seems able to provide an example or a decent explanation. The problem is, that I think `QWidget::createWindowContainer` replaces `QX11EmbedContainer`, not `QX11EmbedWidget`. May you have an idea on how a `QWidget` could be embedded into a non-Qt window using `QWidget::createWindowContainer`?

Comment: I confess - I can't help you with an example,either.  And I didn't find any open-source, 3rd party alternatives.  Q: What is the particular "use case" for QX11EmbedWidget that you'd like to emulate in QT 5.x (QT 5.7?)? Is your "application" GTK, QT or "something else"? Please update your post with this info...